# Why does this Access query require me to log into ODBC again?

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2010, linked-tables

I have an Access 2010 database that has links to several ODBC tables. My username and password were cached when I first linked the tables, so I don't have to re-enter my Login ID and Password everytime I run a query - except on one. I have 20+ queries that are working just fine without having to relogin.

My SQL is below. Is there something intrinsically off in the code, or is it another issue?

```
SELECT DISTINCT IIf(IsNull([LeftSide]![ContactID]),"",CStr([LeftSide]![ContactID])) AS LeftSideContactID, IIf(IsNull([rightSide]![ContactID]),"",CStr([rightSide]![ContactID])) AS RightSideContactID, [RightSide]![Pref] & " & " & [LeftSide]![Pref] AS [Combined Prefix], [RightSide]![FName] & " & " & [LeftSide]![FName] AS [Combined FName], IIf([RightSide]![LName]=[LeftSide]![LName],[RightSide]![LName],[RightSide]![LName] & " & " & [LeftSide]![LName]) AS [Combined LName], [RightSide]![Pref] & " " & [RightSide]![FName] & " " & [RightSide]![LName] & " & " & [LeftSide]![Pref] & " " & [LeftSide]![FName] & " " & [LeftSide]![LName] AS [Combined Mailing Name]
FROM (([Contacts In Query (username)] AS LeftSide INNER JOIN ContactContact ON LeftSide.ContactID = ContactContact.Contact1ID) INNER JOIN [Contacts In Query (username)] AS RightSide ON ContactContact.Contact2ID = RightSide.ContactID) INNER JOIN Relationship ON ContactContact.RelationshipID = Relationship.RelationshipID
WHERE (((Relationship.Relationship) Like "*spouse*"));
```

[Contacts In Query (username)] is a flat table in Access, the others (Relationship and ContactContact) are linked from an external database.

I've got a workaround - oddly, as soon as I changed the joins from `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`, it worked without requiring a login. I then had to use a couple of criteria to approximate an inner join by filtering out results where there wasn't an exact match.

```
SELECT DISTINCT IIf(IsNull([LeftSide]![ContactID]),"",CStr([LeftSide]![ContactID])) AS LeftSideContactID, IIf(IsNull([rightSide]![ContactID]),"",CStr([rightSide]![ContactID])) AS RightSideContactID, [RightSide]![Pref] & " & " & [LeftSide]![Pref] AS [Combined Prefix], [RightSide]![FName] & " & " & [LeftSide]![FName] AS [Combined FName], IIf([RightSide]![LName]=[LeftSide]![LName],[RightSide]![LName],[RightSide]![LName] & " & " & [LeftSide]![LName]) AS [Combined LName], [RightSide]![Pref] & " " & [RightSide]![FName] & " " & [RightSide]![LName] & " & " & [LeftSide]![Pref] & " " & [LeftSide]![FName] & " " & [LeftSide]![LName] AS [Combined Mailing Name]
FROM (([Contacts In Query (username)] AS LeftSide RIGHT JOIN ContactContact ON LeftSide.ContactID = ContactContact.Contact1ID) LEFT JOIN [Contacts In Query (username)] AS RightSide ON ContactContact.Contact2ID = RightSide.ContactID) INNER JOIN Relationship ON ContactContact.RelationshipID = Relationship.RelationshipID
WHERE (((IIf(IsNull([LeftSide]![ContactID]),"",CStr([LeftSide]![ContactID])))<>"") AND ((IIf(IsNull([rightSide]![ContactID]),"",CStr([rightSide]![ContactID])))<>"") AND ((Relationship.Relationship) Like "*spouse*"));
```

Hopefully this will help anyone who's come up against the same issue, but if anyone could shed some light on *why* this is happening, and why this fix works, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Perhaps can this website offer some insight on your odbc cache; http://docs.intersystems.com/cache41/dbc/dbcoconnect.html

Comment: Can you figure out wich table causes prompt for password? There is no magic in IT. It either caches data or reuses opened connection. workaround without understaning what's going on is one's last resort.

Comment: @Stoleg: Oh, absolutely, that's why I added the bounty despite having a workaround; I want to know what's going wrong. None of the tables independently prompts for the password; I can open all of them without needing it. It only prompts for a password when using Inner Joins in that specific setup - as per my workaround in the answers below, changing them to Left and Right joins fixes it, but this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Further to this, I've now moved my workaround into the question itself, as the question has changed from "How do I fix this?" to "Why is this happening?"

Comment: Find a table in question by removing joins from your query. Most probable paths to look for: tables on different DBs and one of them is prompting for password, another - cashing working for all queries but this one as pointed by @JenZzz. This query may be a step in some workflow and password prompt may be at a different step, eg. update or delete.

Comment: A thought. May be `INNER JOIN` is not a valid MsAccess syntax, so it needs to pass to DB at this point and needs a password. `LEFT` and `RIGHT` joins are MsAccess syntax, so code is parsed and executed by Access itself from some cache.

Comment: @Stoleg - Inner Join is valid syntax (http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/inner-join-operation-HA001231487.aspx) and the query was created in the Access query builder. The query also triggers a password check whether run by itself or as part of a workflow. It seems to be ContactContact that's causing the password query, but it doesn't in any context other than Inner Joining to this particular (flat) table.

Comment: Are both tables in the same database, or is there more then one back end (sql server) database? Also, when you linked the tables, did you save the password in the table links?

Comment: Only one back end database. @AlbertD.Kallal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there may be some database corruption in one of the hidden system tables.  Have you tried importing the objects into a new Access database, and then run the original query?  Corrupted objects won't import successfully.

Comment: Yup, that got it. Annoying that it's so simple!